# Access Pivot column using Eloquent and return result as per the condition - Laravel, Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have data in a format shown below, Its a Many to Many Relationship.

I want to retrieve only those entries from relation2 whose value in pivot (is_column1 = 0). How to access pivot in eloquent style?

**query**

```
$data = Relation1::with(['relation2' => function ($query){
    $query->where('col4', '1');
    $query->where('pivot.is_column1', '1'); // I want something like this
}])->get();
```

**result**

```
[
  {
     "id": 1,
     "name": "Test",
     "relation2": 
        [
          {
             "id": 3,
             "col2_id": 1,
             "col3_id": 1,
             "col4": "1",
             "pivot": {
                 "col1_id": 1,
                 "col2_id": 2,
                 "is_column1": "1"
              }
           }
        ] 
     }
 ]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`wherePivot()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) method:

```
Relation1::with(['relation2' => function ($query) {
    $query->where('col4', '1')
        ->wherePivot('is_column1', '1');
}])
->get();
```

Answer (score 2):

It is much easier if you have pivot tables that connects the two tables (especially with many-to-many relationships). I suggest that you create a pivot table which table name must be in alphabetical order between the tables (best way is to create a migration for that).

Example if you have users and tags, pivot table must be in singular form

```
user_tag
```

`user_tag` table must have the `user_id` and `tag_id` columns available.

Then along the lines of User.php, make a function which Laravel can understand that it is a property

```
public function tags() {
    $this->belongsToMany(Tag::class);
}
```

And vice versa. After declaring relationships between the models, Laravel will automatically look into the `user_tag` table (make sure it is alphabetical in order, otherwise it will not work).

You can do something in the likes of this:

`$user->tags; // returns all tag records in database associated in the pivot table`
`$tag->users; // returns all users associated with tag`

Doing so you can access the properties of the users or tags through relationship

`$user->tags()->pluck('name');`

Something like that